# Average time for a brute force attack given 200 try per second

Tags: brute-force-attack

This is from an exam question.

> What is the average time to success at a brute force attack on a 56-bits key algorithm, if you're able to make 200 tries per seconds?

Let's suppose we got a crypted and decrypted version of a given text, so we know instantly if the attack is succesful or not.

The given answer to this question was **5700 years**, but that's not what I found. Here's my reasonning :

There is 2^56 possible keys. We need to calculate *average* time, so we'll only need to try (2^56)/2 possibilities.

We have 200 tries per second, so we'll need (2^56)/(2*200) seconds to try them all. That's 1.8014399e+14 seconds

(1.8014399e+14)/(60*60*24*365) = **5712328.45003 years**.

Where's my error?

Comment: Perhaps there really are 200 tries per millisecond?

Comment: No, it's really per second.

Comment: $2^{10}\approx10^3$ (plus 2.4%), thus $(2^{55}/200)\text s$ is $\approx(32\cdot10^{15}/200)\text s$ (plus a little over 12%) or $\approx(3.2\cdot10^{14}/2)\text s$. As the saying goes, $\pi$ seconds is a nanocentury, that is $3.14\cdot10^7\text s$ is next to a year, thus we are talking $10^7/2$ years (and  then some), just as you computed.

Comment: Ok then. Guess the error was on the exam side.